# Is there an infinite−dimensional Banach subspace in C^∞([0,1])  ?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

More specifically, with $I=[0,1]$ let $E=(X,\mathcal T\ )=C^\infty(I)$, where $X$ is the underlying (say real) vector space and $\mathcal T\ $ is the (standard projective limit) topology of uniform convergence of each fixed derivative. One asks whether there is a $\mathcal T\ $−closed infinite−dimensional vector subspace $S$ in $X$ such that $S$ with the induced vector operations and the induced topology is Banach(able). This requires existence of a zero neighbourhood $V$ in $E$ such that $S\cap V$ be bounded in $E$. Still more explicitly, we should have some natural number $k$ and a sequence $i\mapsto M_i$ of positive reals such that whenever $x\in S$ is such that $|D^ix(t)|\le 1$ for all natural $i$ up to $k$ and all $t\in I$, then we also have $|D^ix(t)|\le M_i$ for all $i$ up to $\infty$ and $t\in I$. My guess after trying some examples is that there **is not** such an $S$, but I have no proof for this.

Comment: Since the author appears to have answered his or her own question (as has Silver) I think he or she should accept one of these two answers

Comment: I would like to accept my own answer because it uses more elementary facts but I must wait for 32 hours before I can do so!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a many years lasting problem to me, but now that I began to think of it anew, I found the solution: Since $E$ has the Heine−Borel property, taking $V$ to be $\mathcal T\ $−closed, we get $S\cap V$ also such, and hence $\mathcal T\ $−compact. Having a compact zero neighbourhood, so $S$ must be finite−dimensional. No such complicated things as nuclearity are needed. The same argument also gives the same result for the space $E=\mathbb R^{{\ \mathbb N}_0}$ .

Comment: If by $E={\bf R}^{\bf N}$ you mean the Banach space of bounded sequences, this is incorrect, as $E$ does not have the Heine-Borel property (as no infinite-dimensional Banach space has it) AND $E$ contains many infinite-dimensional Banach subspaces (even if you don't include itself), such as $\ell^p$, for $p\ge 1$.

Comment: Concerning the main thrust of your argument, it seems you are assuming that you can choose a bounded neighborhood of $E$ (so that its closure is bounded and the intersection of that with $S$ will be closed and bounded, so compact by Heine-Borel). However, $E$ does not have any bounded neighborhoods (a tvs with the Heine-Borel property and a bounded neighborhood is automatically finite-dimensional).

Comment: To BR: By ${\mathbb R}^{{\ \mathbb N}_0}$ is meant, as is usual, the Fréchet space of all real valued sequences equipped with the topology of pointwise convergence. I do not assume $E$ to have any bounded zero neighbourhood. Only $S\cap V$ will be bounded, not $V$ . You should think the matter more accurately!

Comment: You could help by explaining why $S\cap V$ must be bounded in $E$. Not every neighborhood of a Banach space is bounded, so without restrictions on $V$, you can't say $S\cap V$ is bounded in $S$. And I just don't know what needs to be said to go from "bounded in $S$" to "bounded in $E$". If you are using specifics about your $E$, you might want to mention them. Of course, you are answering your own question, so it may not matter to you how clear it is to others.

Comment: Again to BR: I am new here (but not in mathematics) and I thought MO should be a place (mainly) for research level mathematicians. So not every detail of beginning undergraduate level should be explained. Nevertheless, ... . To be explicit, write $F$ for the Banachable space obtained by equipping the (abstract) set $S$ with the induced vector space operations and topology from $E$. To be continued ...

Comment: In my question, I wrote: "... This requires existence of a zero neighbourhood $V$ in $E$ such that $S\cap V$ be bounded in $E$. ..." This means that we can always *choose* a bounded zero neighbourhood in a normable, hence in particular in a Banachable space. After choosing one such, say $U$ in $F$, we may choose another, say $V$ in $E$ so that $U=S\cap V$. This follows directly from the definition of the induced topology. Zero neighbourhoods in $F$ are exactly the $S\cap V$ for $V$ a zero neighbourhood in $E$. Using this, it then follows that $S\cap V$ is bounded also in $E$.

Comment: My point in commenting was that what you wrote in your answer is not what you actually meant. You literally chose your $V$ to be a closed neighborhood, when you actually meant to choose $V$ so that $S\cap V$ would be bounded. Now that I understand the situation, here is my version of your argument. Choose a closed bounded neighborhood $U$ of $S$. $U$ is closed in $E$. Boundedness is also simple: given a neighborhood $V$ of $E$, there is a $t_0$ so that $t\cdot (V\cap S)\supset U$, and thus $t\cdot V\supset U$, for all $t>t_0$. So $U$ is bounded in $E$, hence compact.

Comment: This can be rephrased as "closed subspaces of Heine-Borel spaces are Heine-Borel". Then your argument is precisely Silver's, with nuclear replaced with the Heine-Borel property.

Comment: **Again to BR.** You commented me: "You literally chose your $V$ to be a closed neighborhood, when you actually meant to choose $V$ so that $S\cap V$ would be bounded." In my original question, I already wrote " ... zero neighbourhood $V$ in $E$ such that $S\cap V$ be bounded in $E$ ". So I did not consider it worth while repeating. I think you stick to points not worth of it. The essential content of my argument in my answer is the same as in my comment to Silver's answer, but more explicit. I am glad that you finally understood it.

Answer (score 11):

I guess that the answer is NO.

Since

- $C^\infty(I)$ is nuclear,
- any closed subspace of a nuclear space is nuclear,
- any nuclear Banach space is finite-dimensional.

Edit : for another proof, replace "nuclear" by "Fréchet-Montel".

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail on your second point? (My general TVS knowledge/facility is somewhat rusty)

Comment: In *Topological uniform structures* by Warren Page, Wiley 1988, on page 237, Definition 20.8 says that a Hausdorff locally convex space is *semi-Montel* iff bounded subsets are relatively compact. By requiring also infrabarrelledness, we get *Montel spaces*. On page 238, Theorem 20.10 says that closed (vector)subspaces of semi-Montel spaces are semi-Montel. Also (arbitrary) products of semi-Montel spaces are semi-Montel. In particular, we get the result that *no **semi-Montel** space can contain an infinite-dimensional **normable** subspace*.